# Install Cuda 11.0 on Ubuntu: kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-34-generic is not supported

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I try to install Cuda Toolkit 11.0, I follow every single line successfully of the Installation Instructions of NVIDIA except the last one:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

When I run the last line... I get the following

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                      
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                           
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                  
cuda-11-0 is already the newest version (11.0.2-1).                                                                                                                                                                
cuda-11-0 set to manually installed.                                                                                                                                                                               
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:                                                                                                                                       
  linux-modules-5.8.0-53-generic                                                                                                                                                                                   
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.                                                                                                                                                                            
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.                                                                                                                                                     
8 not fully installed or removed.                                                                                                                                                                                  
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.                                                                                                                                                   
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y                                                                                                                                                                                   
Setting up nvidia-dkms-450 (450.51.05-0ubuntu1) ...                                                                                                                                                                
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
A modprobe blacklist file has been created at /etc/modprobe.d to prevent Nouveau                                                                                                                                   
from loading. This can be reverted by deleting the following file:                                                                                                                                                 
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please regenerate your                                                                                                                                        
initrd by running the following command after deleting the modprobe.d file:                                                                                                                                        
`/usr/sbin/initramfs -u`                                                                                                                                                                                           

*****************************************************************************                                                                                                                                      
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***                                                                                                                                      
*** be loaded.                                                            ***                                                                                                                                      
*****************************************************************************                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
INFO:Enable nvidia                                                                                                                                                                                                 
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here                                                                                                                                         
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad                                                                                                                                              
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude                                                                                                                                                
Removing old nvidia-450.51.05 DKMS files...                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                     
Deleting module version: 450.51.05                                                                                                                                                                                 
completely from the DKMS tree.                                                                                                                                                                                     
------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                     
Done.                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Loading new nvidia-450.51.05 DKMS files...                                                                                                                                                                         
Building for 5.11.0-34-generic                                                                                                                                                                                     
Building for architecture x86_64                                                                                                                                                                                   
Building initial module for 5.11.0-34-generic                                                                                                                                                                      
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.11.0-34-generic is not supported                                                                                                                               
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.11.0-34-generic (x86_64)                                                                                                                                    
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/450.51.05/build/make.log for more information.                                                                                                                                        
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-450 (--configure):                                                                                                                                                      
 installed nvidia-dkms-450 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10                                                                                                               
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-450:                                                                                                                                              
 nvidia-driver-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1); however:                                                                                                                                     
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-450 (--configure):                                                                                                                                                    
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured                                                                                                                                                                        
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.                                                                                                         
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure
.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-450:                                                                                                                                              
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-dkms-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-450 is not configured yet.
 cuda-drivers-450 depends on nvidia-driver-450 (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package nvidia-driver-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-450 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-450 (= 450.51.05-1); however:
  Package cuda-drivers-450 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-11-0:
 cuda-runtime-11-0 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 450.51.05); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-11-0:
 cuda-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-11-0:
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0 depends on cuda-runtime-11-0; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-11-0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda:
 cuda depends on cuda-11-0 (>= 11.0.2); however:
  Package cuda-11-0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.6) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-34-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-450
 nvidia-driver-450
 cuda-drivers-450
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-11-0
 cuda-11-0
 cuda-demo-suite-11-0
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64
- NVIDIA GeForce MX150

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release details; but neither of the 5.8 kernel (from 20.10) or 5.11 (from 21.04) are supported by Ubuntu either, as the releases that used them are EOL.  What OS/release are you using? as I see no kernel versions that are on-topic on this site (*none supported*)

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastin Castro Quispe, the latest CUDA doesn't support older GPU.  Probably best to check on Nvidia website whether your GPU can work with the latest CUDA.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon I just updated the post, I'm now including my GPU and OS.

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon According to this [post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/which-version-of-cuda-is-compatible-with-nvidia-mx-150/74400) my NVIDIA MX150 works with CUDA 10. however, I have not found if it works as well with CUDA 11.

Comment: Try using a *supported* kernel, which for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is the GA kernel stack (5.4) or with HWE 5.15.  Your 5.11 kernel is *unsupported* being from 21.04; it was replaced with 5.13 from 21.10 then 5.15 from 22.04, Your system is behind on upgrades as 20.04.3 shows (*a fully upgraded system currently shows as [20.04.4](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) with the .5 changes rolling out already, but the .5 name change having occurred yet*). Installed systems get upgrades before ISO release date (*my used link*)